# SignalR is not responding after few minutes

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

[image: Network tab details filter with WS][image]I am trying to implement signalR in React and API side using .net Core. for some time the response is coming. Below is the trace info from brower where i am getting the response

```
Information: Normalizing '/hubUrl' to 'https://localhost:############'. Utils.js:159 
[2023-06-27T13:14:28.126Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection. Utils.js:159 
[2023-06-27T13:14:28.126Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'. Utils.js:159 
[2023-06-27T13:14:28.127Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting. Utils.js:159 
[2023-06-27T13:14:28.161Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 31194.
```

I am trying to implement signalR in React and API side using .net Core.for some time the response is coming.Below is the trace info from brower where i am getting the response

```
Information: Normalizing '/hubUrl' to '`[`https://localhost`](https://localhost)`:############'.Utils.js:159 
[2023-06-27T13:14:28.126Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection. Utils.js:159 
[2023-06-27T13:14:28.126Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.` Utils.js:159 
[2023-06-27T13:14:28.127Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting. Utils.js:159 
[2023-06-27T13:14:28.161Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 31194.
```

but after some time getting the below response continuously

```
**Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 11. **
**Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 11. **
**Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 11. **
**Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 11. **
```

Bewlow are the start up config

`<pre>`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllers();


endpoints.MapHub<hubname>("/hubname", options =>
{
    options.Transports =
        HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
});
});


services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);
    hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

});
services.AddScoped<HubName>();
```

Below are react code for signalR

```
var tryingToReconnect = false;
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/hubUrl", {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
})
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
.build();

connection.on("hubname", function (response) {
console.log("hubname", response);


setData(response);
    setLoading(false);
});


connection.start({ transport: ['webSockets'] }).then(() => {
    connection
      .invoke("hubmethod")
      .catch(err => console.error("invoke", err));
});

 
connection.onclose(function () {
    //TODO: write the logic to reconnect to server.
    if (!tryingToReconnect) {
        // notifyclient about disconnection
        
            setTimeout(function () {
                connection.start({ transport: ['webSockets'] }).then(function () {
                  connection
                    .invoke("hubmethod")
                    .catch(err => console.error("invoke", err));
                  }) 
              }, 1);
      }
  });
  connection.onreconnecting(function () {
      tryingToReconnect = true;
     
  });
   connection.onreconnected(function () {
      tryingToReconnect = false;
      
  });



connection.onclose -- never executing
```

[image: Error]
[image: debug details]
[image: Error tab details and marked line of code that having issue]
[image: Code for using signalR]

[WS network tab details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxnlf.jpg)

Comment: You should add `connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 20000;` in client side.

Comment: Please share the screenshot with error for us, you can find it in Developer Tools.

Comment: Hi @JasonPan i have added browser console details.

Comment: will add connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 20000; as well and check

Comment: Hi BHARTI， the screenshot you shared was info, not including error, you can click the error options in the left panel, then share it

Comment: Hi @JasonPan i have added console error details

Comment: Ok, I think the issue is due to server side not send ping message to client side, you could [check the ws trace inside network trace in browser developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW7aE.png). And you will found not type6 message.

Comment: What we can do only to [enable server side logs, like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX31i.png).

Comment: Hi @JasonPan i have added more screen shots. 1) network tab with ws details 2) error tab details and marked the line of code that have issue 3) signalR code that i am using. he here once that code goes to catch block i am reloading the page ( for the time being). i am facing this issue for a long time.  help/guidance will be very appreciated

Comment: I havn't seen the ws tab information.

Comment: I need to check if there are type6 messages in ws tab.

Comment: Hi @JasonPan. i think i found the issue. in WS network tab details type6 messages are coming as empty. added the screenshot . please have a look. and provide some idea/suggestion to fix this

Comment: The type 6 empty message is normal, it just a heartbeat message. Could you re-create a minimal sample project for us to troubleshoot.